# How to create custom keyboard in xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have implemented cross platform app with a custom keyboard, I need to dispatch a keyboard event for xamarin IOS, The following code I can dispatch the event on xamarin Android.

```
webView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEventActions.Down, KeyEvent.KeyCodeFromString(digit), 0, MetaKeyStates.ShiftLeftOn | MetaKeyStates.CtrlOn));
webView.DispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEventActions.Up, KeyEvent.KeyCodeFromString(digit), 0, MetaKeyStates.ShiftLeftOn | MetaKeyStates.CtrlOn));
```

I need to get the equivalent for xamarin iOS. Please let me know if you know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the **custom renderer** of content page which contins the webview and add the event of keyboard .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using ObjCRuntime;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage),typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyPageRenderer:PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, new Selector("KeyboardWillShow"), new NSString("UIKeyboardWillShowNotification"), null);

            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, new Selector("KeyboardWillHide"), new NSString("UIKeyboardWillHideNotification"), null);
        }

        [Export("KeyboardWillShow")]
        void KeyboardWillShow()
        {

        }

        [Export("KeyboardWillHide")]
        void KeyboardWillHide()
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas Zhang, i need to dispatch a key event like android. In android, i did sent a key from custom keyboard and dispatched in key event.

Comment: `Entry` has an event called `TextChanged`.Whichhat is raised when the text in this Entry element is changed. You can get the value of you input in the event and handle the logic .